# Compiling Linux Kernel Module With A Custom Header

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, kernel, kbuild

I would like to compile a simple character device module depending on a custom header. The folder is thus organized,

```
+ mymod.c
| customized-header.h
| customized-header.c
| Makefile
```

In `mymod.c`, the header is thus used,

```
#include "customized-header.h"
```

In Makefile:

```
obj-m := mymod.o
mymod-objs := customized-header.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
PWD = $(shell pwd)
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Everything should work fine, the module gets compiled without problem, I can load the module through `sudo insmod`, but the module doesn't work properly. When I checked `nm mymod.ko`, there are a lot of vars and functions are missing. It looks as if it stopped after linking `customized_header.o`. If I remove this header and its function, say no header function calls from the module, it compiles perfectly with desired result.

Could you see what went wrong here?

Comment: What happens when you change the obj-m line to: obj-m := mymod.o customized-header.o?

Comment: @PeterL. Well, `obj-m` is to generate a module. When I added `customized-header.o`, some more files are generated: like `customized-header.ko`. In the meantime, `mymod.ko` is still the same. Here I would like only one module, which is `mymod.ko`, the `customized-header` works like a library for the module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem resides in the `Makefile`. Due to the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701658/kernel-module-with-multiple-files-unknown-symbol?rq=1), I changed it into

```
obj-m: mymodko.o
mymodko-obj: customized-header.o mymod.o
```

It now works fine. So the question was the naming of module object. We need to specify different names as in this case `mymodko.o` and `mymod.o`.

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber I need to wait for another 20 hours to accept my own answer.