# Including custom headers in Linux modules

Tags: c, linux, makefile, kernel-module

Before anyone points this out, a similar question was answered here before:
[Compiling Linux Kernel Module With A Custom Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119710/compiling-linux-kernel-module-with-a-custom-header)

I have the same issue. I created my own set of structs and functions and defined them in a C file. Then I created a header file of the same name and included it in a module. Then I created the Makefile:

```
obj-m += themodule.o
themodule-objs := the-module.o my-code.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

My custom files are my-code.c and my-code.h.

When I tried to compile the module, I received a ton of warning, telling me that all the functions from my-code.c were undefined in the-module.c. When I tried to load the module, I received errors, telling me that the function calls to my-code.c were "unknown symbols". I tried the solution mentioned in the linked question (see Makefile), but that did not do the trick for me. Any thoughts?

Comment: can you copy & paste you *unknonw symbols* errors and the compile warnings?

Answer (score 2):

The order in *themodule-objs* matters. Try this:

```
obj-m += themodule.o
themodule-objs := my-code.o the-module.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still got the same warnings and errors however.